# Can't login to Dragon's Call

Tags: dragons-call

I tried to refresh my Dragon's Call page and now I get this error:

Server Error in '/' Application.

Runtime Error

Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.

Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote machines, please create a  tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This  tag should then have its "mode" attribute set to "Off".

Notes: The current error page you are seeing can be replaced by a custom error page by modifying the "defaultRedirect" attribute of the application's  configuration tag to point to a custom error page URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

apparently it was blocked in our office. the game has different servers for the app itself and the login. the game wasn't blocked, but the login server was.